# How to load the RVM part of user's .bashrc to run Ruby CGI scripts under Apache?

Tags: ruby, apache, cgi, rvm

I've configured a new server on Ubuntu 12.04 and I started to use RVM.

I've installed RVM under my user (as myself, not as root with sudo) by following the [Ryan Bigg's guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/), with no previous system-wide installed Ruby. So, I didn't have any Ruby under /usr/bin. My first task then was to replace the shebang line of all my CGI scripts, from

```
!#/usr/bin/ruby
```

to

```
!#/usr/bin/env ruby
```

However my scripts didn't run under Apache. In the terminal I could run them (by typing `./index.cgi`, for example), but not over a browser. A relevant note: in both the user is the same, i.e., the Apache user is the same as the one logged on terminal. Through php tests, I've checked the RVM enviroment (last lines of `.bashrc`) was not loaded under Apache.

I saw [this tip for running CGI scripts with RVM](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/5397/how-to-use-rvm-installs-of-ruby-in-shell-cgi-scripts/), which suggests to put the complete path of specific version of Ruby in the shebang line. That can be useful if you have scripts which run on different versions of Ruby. But that solution doesn't work for me, because my scripts must run on different machines, with different users and different paths.

The solution which works for me is to put a symlink of the desired Ruby version under /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -s /home/apache_user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p370/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

But I want to know if there's a better solution, because I guess that `rvm --default use` is better than `sudo ln -s`.

I am thinking about:

- loading the RVM Environment on startup (but I don't know how to achieve that);
- loading the RVM Environment for each web request (which can degrade performance, and I don't know how to configure Apache to do that);
- maybe the RVM Environment is loaded and all I must do is to guess the name of relevant variables to pass with `PassEnv` directive. But I doubt that. (Why Apache would run the `.bashrc` instead of another shell like `csh` or `ksh`?)

Answer (score 1):

you can source the ruby environment, I'm not sure if it's enough to source it in `$HOME` for apache or if you need to modify `/etc/init.d/apache2`, but the line is:

```
source /path/to/rvm/environments/<name>
```

where for `<name>` you can either use full ruby name or an alias name

You can create aliases with:

```
rvm alias create veve 1.9.3-p125@my-project
```

which for RVM installed in `/home/app/.rvm` will allow you to use:

```
source /home/app/.rvm/environments/veve
```

in `.bashrc` or `/etc/init.d/apache2` (just near top, bellow shebang).

Answer (score 0):

you could always do

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

That will link the default version of the rvm-managed Ruby to `/usr/bin/ruby` and you will never have to do anything. set it and forget it.